# Javascript project templates Win App store

Tags: javascript, windows, html, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

Short question, where to find the Javascript templates for Windows Apps?

As described in the follow link:
[Javascript project templates for store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758331.aspx)

Tried Googling and trying to search inside Visual Studio with no avail (JS templates are not installed by default). Searching Online through Visual Studio returns nothing of value.

Using Visual Studio Express Update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason a fresh clean install did install all the templates except for the JavaScript ones.
A (lengthy) repair of Visual Studio 2013 Express did the trick!